# How to create a window in Unity from a script and attach it to an existing tab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

i'm trying to make a custom editor script for Unity, but i'm stuck in what I thought would be an easy step.
When using UnityEditor.GetWindow(), the window doesn't open in the main tab but as a separate Window. [The scene view is not attached to the main Unity window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcOxv.png)

I've tried a few workarounds but none seem to work:

- First I tried to use the desiredDockNextTo parameter from the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.GetWindow.html), but I keep getting an error i'm not able to fix.

  ```
    Type inspWndType = typeof(Editor).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.SceneView");

   EditorWindow[] allWindows = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<EditorWindow>();
   Type[] insWindTypeList = new Type[allWindows.Length];
   for(int i = 0; i < allWindows.Length; i++)
   {
       insWindTypeList[i] = allWindows[i].GetType();
   }
   var window = EditorWindow.GetWindow<typeof(inspWndType)>(insWindTypeList);
  ```

I keep getting an error in <typeof(inspWndType)> saying that it's a variable instead of a type *(I also tried with inspWndType.gettype or casting it, nothing worked).*

- Also tried using [Jayatubi's Docker](https://gist.github.com/Jayatubi/f6cafb4d5a5fcb54b537e79be77aa714) and it didn't work either.

TLDR: I want to be able to create a window using EditorWindow.GetWindow() and dock it from a script.

Thank you to anyone that could help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `typeof` expects a compile time constant type not a dynamic variable.

So if something it should be e.g.

```
var inspWndType = typeof(UnityEditor.SceneView);
```

However, the second issue: You can't have this as generic type parameter.

What you want to do is assuming your editorwindow looks like e.g.

```
public class YOURWINDOW : EditorWindow
{
    ...
}
```

then it should rather be

```
var inspWndType = typeof(UnityEditor.SceneView);
var window = EditorWindow.GetWindow<YOURWINDOW>(inspWndType);
```

There is no reflection needed here as you don't want o deal with any runtime types and `UnityEditor.SceneView` is public anyway.

---

Example:

```
using System;
using UnityEditor;

public class ExampleWindow : EditorWindow
{
    [MenuItem("Examples/ExampleWindow")]
    private static void Init()
    {
        var inspWndType = typeof(SceneView);
        var window = GetWindow<ExampleWindow>(inspWndType);
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Tadaaaa!", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

Now **if** you actually want to have it docked no matter what tab is opened you could use reflection to find just each and every inheritor of `EditorWindow` and do

```
using Linq;

...

var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes()).Where(type =>type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EditorWindow))).ToArray();
// This kind of equals doing something like
//var typesList = new List<Type>();
//var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
//foreach(var assembly in assemblies)
//{
//    var allTypes = assembly.GetTypes();
//    foreach(var type in allTypes)
//    {
//        if(type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EditorWindow)))
//        {
//            typesList.Add(type);
//        }
//    }
//}
//var types = typesList.ToArray();

var window = GetWindow<YOURWINDOW>(types);
```

Note though that due to order the `ConsoleWindow` is kinda the first entry almost so if there is a console tab opened it would always first attach to that one ^^

You can still add your preferred ones though like e.g.

```
var types = new List<Type>()
{ 
    // first add your preferences
    typeof(SceneView), 
    typeof(Editor).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.GameView"),
    typeof(Editor).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.SceneHierarchyWindow"),
    typeof(Editor).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.ConsoleWindow"), 
    typeof(Editor).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.ProjectBrowser"), 
    typeof(Editor).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.InspectorWindow")
};

// and then add all others as fallback (who cares about duplicates at this point ? ;) )
types.AddRange(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes()).Where(type =>type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EditorWindow))));
var window = GetWindow<YOURWINDOW>(types.ToArray());
```

since it literally goes through this array from start to end and uses the first matching opened window type.

Comment: You helped me a lot, but is there any way to get other types of unity windows?
I want to use some other basic window types and i can't find any public reference for them. More specifically I'd need SceneHierarchyWindow, GameView, ConsoleWindow, InspectorWindow and ProjectBrowser. I don't know if there's a way to access them easily, but trying UnityEditor.<WindowName> didn't work for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SalvioCalvilloMatas `Debug.Log(string.Join('\n', AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes()).Where(type =>type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract&& type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EditorWindow))).Select(t => t.FullName)));` will give you a complete list of anything inheriting from `EditorWindow` in the console ;)

Comment: @SalvioCalvilloMatas your specific ones you will need to get via reflection as shown e.g. `typeof(Editor).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.InspectorWindow")`, `typeof(Editor).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.ConsoleWindow")`, `typeof(Editor).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.ProjectBrowser")` etc because they are not public

Comment: It's not possible to use GetWindow<T> with non-public windows? With the typeof there's the same problem as before, that it passes as a variable.
`Type test = typeof(Editor).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.InspectorWindow");
var window = EditorWindow.GetWindow<test> (types.ToArray());`

Comment: @SalviCalvillo there is no need to use `GetWindow` for the internal windows as you do not want to open one of these windows you rather want to open **your** window next to one of them. **IF** you really wanted to actively open one of the other windows you will need to use the non-generic overload `ar window = EditorWindow.GetWindow(test);` but you will not be able to attach those ... though i sounds like in such case you rather want to use a custom window Layout ;)

Comment: It would've been great if it was possible to attach two windows easily from script i believe, i'll take a look at custom window layouts. You have helped me a lot, thank you!